# Current IPv4 blocks allocated to each country / city / organization

Tags: geolocation, ip, ipv4

I would like to understand better the current ipv4 address space and need help finding data about the ip allocation for each country. If possible, going further for each city, [ISP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_service_provider) and organization.

I understand that the IPv4 addresses are controlled by 5 major [Regional Internet Registries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_Internet_Registry) that together form the [Number Resource Organization](http://www.nro.net/). Each RIR manages addresses for the following countries:

> - African Network Information Centre ([AfriNIC](http://www.afrinic.net/)) for Africa
> - American Registry for Internet Numbers ([ARIN](http://www.arin.net/)) for the United States, Canada, several parts of the Caribbean region, and Antarctica.
> - Asia-Pacific Network Information Centre ([APNIC](http://www.apnic.net/)) for Asia, Australia, New Zealand, and neighboring countries
> - Latin America and Caribbean Network Information Centre ([LACNIC](http://www.lacnic.net/)) for Latin America and parts of the Caribbean region
> - Réseaux IP Européens Network Coordination Centre ([RIPE NCC](http://www.ripe.net/)) for Europe, Russia, the Middle East, and Central Asia
>
> -- [*from wikipedia*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_Internet_Registry)

Being 5 separate organizations (each one with a different commercial presentation on their websites), I could not find a centralized place with an exhaustive map with all the allocated blocks

I found this [site](http://www.nirsoft.net/countryip/) with the ip blocks and assigned countries. Thats part of what I want. Also I dont know if this is reliable

Also, this [xkcd comic](http://xkcd.com/195/) plays with the same data that I am looking for. The comic is probably based on this [interesting image](http://www.caida.org/research/id-consumption/census-map/images/20061108.pnghttp://IPv4http://www.caida.org/research/id-consumption/census-map/images/20061108.png). According to [CAIDA](http://www.caida.org/research/id-consumption/census-map/) (The Cooperative Association for Internet Data Analysis), the image is a result of 2 months of ICMP exploration back in 2006:

> *A visualization of IPv4 addresses that responded to ICMP (ping) packets during a two-month (very slow) scan of the IPv4 address space. Some hosts do not respond to the probes due to firewalls, NAT boxes, and ICMP filtering. Thus, the data and map give us a lower bound on IPv4 address utilization.*

From the same site, they talk about the Census data source:

> The census data was provided by Information Sciences Institute at the University of Southern California. Internet Addresses Survey dataset, DHS PREDICT ID USC-LANDER/internet_address_survey_it15w-20061108. Traces taken 2006-11-08 to 2007-01-08. Provided by the USC/LANDER project. http://www.isi.edu/ant/lander/. Additional support comes from NSF grant SCI-0427144 and ARIN but does not necessarily reflect the opinions of any of the sponsoring organizations.

I tried finding the pointed dataset and traces but had no success.

I understand that this is essential for the current geolocation solutions, so I would like to understand where their data come from

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to get this information:

A list of allocated or assigned IP addresses and AS number is published by each RIR, and they provide mirrors for each other's data. Take a look at ftp://ftp.ripe.net/pub/stats/. Look for the delegated-* files. They contain lines like:

```
    ripencc|NL|ipv4|37.77.56.0|2048|20120201|allocated
    ripencc|NL|ipv6|2a00:8640::|32|20120130|allocated
```

The country codes listed here are very rough indications of where an address is going to be used. Geolocation companies might use this as a basis, but they have much more accurate data from cooperation with big web stores etc.

PS: the RIRs are not companies, they are membership organisations. Everybody who needs IP addresses can become a member, get voting rights at the AGM, etc. Their policies are determined by an even wider community where everyone can participate (see http://www.ripe.net/ripe/policies).